# Display array values not repeadly

Tags: php

I have the following array

```
$ar = array ( 1,2,3,4,5,3,6,7,...)
```

i do a foreach to display elements like

```
$i = 0
foreach ($ar as $tab){

echo $tab[i];

$i++
}
```

I dont want to display twice the same value like 3.
i just want `1 2 3 4 5 6 7...`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`array_unique`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to get the unique set of values from your array before iterating over it:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,3,6,7);
foreach (array_unique($arr) as $tab)
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try `array_unique`

Answer (score 0):

You may use flip-flip-merge technique which is faster than array_unique()

```
$ar = array(1,2,3,4,5,3,6,7);
$ar = array_merge(array_flip(array_flip($ar)));
```

You may read about it here http://thebatesreport.com/blog/?p=9

Comment: That article is more than 4 years old.

Comment: and? I tested it with PHP 5.3 Results >>>
0.0122 (flip-flip-merge)
0.514 (array_unique)

Comment: linux 2.6.32-5-686-bigmem, php 5.3.2: 0m19.412s (flipper) vs. 0m19.123s (unique) (a few thousand iterations of course)

Comment: It does seem terribly dependent on the actual data, whether there _are_ doubles, etc.

Comment: thank you guys, your solution ( array_unique) does the job. But my array is more complex than the exemple i gave. Am going to  see how to adapt !